# Rails - cUrl GET with session cookie information - Getting 401

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, curl, cookies, http-status-code-401

I am trying to cUrl GET a Rails URL in a hosted application.  To test, I want to use a logged in session in my browser.  I grabbed the cookies from the browser tab and passed it to cUrl command, but it's giving 401 Not Authorized.

I am using

```
curl -H 'session: 2asdfjlksfja32asdfuyio24fasdf' http://my-url/some-path
```

The session is the key that is sent by browser to the server.

Answer (score 1):

How are you sending the cookies? 
According to the curl documentation you should use the `-b, --cookie STRING/FILE  Read cookies from STRING/FILE (H)` option.

The way you are using the `-H` is to set a header with "Session:" which is not a [standard HTTP header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Request_fields)

From a signed in browser, use developer tools (Network tab) to inspect the raw headers in the request sent to the server, then try to replicate the Headers and Cookies using the curl command.